# ng-template angular crea o elimina una instancia, cada vez que hace show o hide

Tags: angular4, bootstrap-4, angular2-template

estoy probando los tabssets de [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/examples) y tengo esta estructura en el html.

```
<ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab title="Simple">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <lamb-form-print-document
        [entities]="entities"
        [departments]="departments"
        [voucherTypes]="voucherTypes"
        [dataInit]="printDocumentDataInit"
        [titleLegend]="titleLegend"
        (onChangeEntity)="onChangeEntity($event)"
        ></lamb-form-print-document>
    </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab>
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle><b>Fancy</b> title</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
    <p>Art party scenester stumptown, tumblr butcher vero
        sint qui sapiente accusamus tattooed echo park.</p>
    </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab title="Disabled" [disabled]="true">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <p>Sed commodo,vel tellus pulvinar feugiat.</p>
    </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

typescript:

```
export class PrintingDocumentsEditComponent implements OnInit {
  public titleLegend: object;      
  public entities: Entity[];
  public departments: Departament[];
  public voucherTypes: VoucherType[];
  public printDocumentDataInit: any;
```

si se fijan ingreso datos `lamb-form-print-document` la primera vez que carga la pagina carga de los normal pero cuando me muevo de un tab a otro, t regreso al tab que contiene el componente formulario. el formularios se limpia.

hasta donde estuve leyendo, esto sucede porque el `<ng-template>` que usa los tabs de ng-bootstrap generan esta accion, osea estos detruyen y contruyen intancias de lo que contiene dentro de la etiketa segun lo requiera. lo que necesito es que no se destruya los datos cuando paso de un tab a otro.
Si es necesario puede dar algunas sugerencias para modificar el tabset de ng-bootstrap, ya que estoy creando un personalizado utlizando como guia los tabsets de ng-bootstrap.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estas buscando es `[destroyOnHide]=` por defecto viene seteado en `True`

```
<ngb-tabset [destroyOnHide]="false">
   // Contenido    
</ngb-tabset>
```